# Where can I obtain the content of closed MOOCs?

Tags: open-access, mooc, repository

MOOCs are often not as open as their name would suggest. For example, [Coursera will soon remove hundreds of classes from its website](https://www.class-central.com/report/coursera-old-platform-shutdown-download-courses), and many courses are not open for enrollment after the course is over.

Where can I obtain the content of closed MOOCs?

I am aware of http://academictorrents.com but it doesn't contain many MOOCs. Are there any more complete resources?

**Disclaimer: this post does not advocate illegal or unethical behavior.**

Comment: According to their [TOS](https://www.coursera.org/about/terms), redistributing material downloaded from Coursera is almost certainly a copyright violation, outside of the situation where the material can be obtained under an open license.

Comment: What you're asking for seems illegal. (Mildly, but still.) I don't think StackExchange is the place for this kind of information.

Comment: @user37208 seems, or is?

Comment: @WillieWong Coursera's ToS tend to be on the conservative side, which is quite unfortunate. I am ready to bet that most active users have infringed it already. Luckily, there are other MOOC platforms. Also, some MOOCs on Coursera may have some open license, as you pointed out.

Comment: My point is same as that of @user37208; I would be much happier if your question specifically ask about MOOC platforms with open licenses, or in some way is restricted to course content that can be legally redistributed.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I said "seems" because I'm not a lawyer, but it's almost certainly a copyright violation in many jurisdictions. And simply on ethical grounds, if the owners of the content are purposely not making it freely available, seeking it out is dodgy at best.

Comment: @user37208 Those are generalities that do not apply in many situations.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Not that I think it's a cardinal sin--I've torrented a textbook or two in my day--but in my mind, academia.stackexchange is a place for learning how to do things the "right" way.

Comment: @WillieWong I do not condone self-censorship.

Comment: @user37208 to me that is the right way.

Comment: At risk of seeming pedantic, I feel like the only answer to this question is, "there isn't a way - else it wouldn't be a *closed* MOOC". Have you considered emailing the course instructors and asking for the material?

Comment: @tonysdg doesn't sound very scalable.

Comment: Scalability was never specified in the question as a requirement ;-) Why are you looking for old/closed MOOC materials? For review? For distribution? For archiving? That might help us answer your question.

Comment: @tonysdg To learn. I sometimes prefer to watch videos that I have already viewed. Also, I sometimes want to check out the materials of a closed MOOC.

Comment: The question deserves a technical answer. It is then up to the user to respect the copyrights and only keep the open licences ones. This long legal debate seems quite out of topics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is possibly advocating illegal or unethical behavior.

Comment: @eykanal unethical is subjective: it is unethical for me to remove educational content. And as stated above it is not necessarily illegal.

Comment: I don't disagree, which is why I wrote "possibly". However, given the discussion, I feel comfortable with the groups assessment that this is a discussion that is not appropriate on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @eykanal why isn't it appropriate? is it because it is illegal in some situations?

Comment: @eykanal I have added a disclaimer: is it okay now?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - lets take this conversation to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44006/room-for-eykanal-and-franck-dernoncourt).

Comment: This is illegal the way it has been asked. You are asking alternative ways to the resources which might include proxy or third party intrusion.

Comment: @Coder as you say, might, but not necessarily…

Comment: @eykanal Since there seems to be no consensus on meta, can you please reopen the question?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Not sure we can safely say "no consensus", there hasn't bene much discussion. Barring someone convincing me otherwise I'm definitely in favor of keeping this closed. That said, if the community votes to reopen I would not object.

Comment: @eykanal Not many people can vote to reopen, and reopen votes expire. There have been 7 upvotes, and 8 dowvotes on this question, so I believe it shouldn't be closed since it means that approximately half the readers are ok with it.

Comment: Continuing the conversation in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44006/room-for-eykanal-and-franck-dernoncourt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to post an answer since some people might have a similar question about MOOC downloads, albeit not in relation to Coursera courses that will be taken down.
3 [legal] solutions:

1. The best way to obtain Coursera content is to download it *when enrolled*. Coursera does allow the download of videos: "You may download content from our Services only for your personal, non-commercial use[...]" see [Coursera T&C](https://www.coursera.org/about/terms/copyright).  [Edx T&C](https://www.edx.org/edx-terms-service) reads: "the [...] video [...] on this Site are for your personal use in connection with those courses only". Bulk download of content can sometimes be against the T&C- I would scan the T&C before making any such attempt.
2. Sign up for future iterations of the course that you wish to obtain. I have oftentimes enrolled in a course, not actively taken (or downloaded) it, only to see that the course was subsequently closed and I could not revisit the content again. By signing up for future iterations, you will be notified as soon as the content will be provided again. In my personal experience of using MOOCs for 4 years now, this is a useful feature that I have benefited from myself. Example: "Advanced Data structures in Java" was previously offered, then taken down, now re-offered: [Course enrolment page](https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-data-structures)
3. Email the course instructors and make your case why you would benefit from the course content. My intuition would be that instructors will be bound by their institution's and Coursera's policies, but it doesn't hurt to ask. They might be able to re-direct you to other (future) courses featuring the same material.

Lastly, I wonder (and this is pure conjecture) whether the soon-non-availability makes the previously uninteresting courses suddenly appealing and a must-have. As mentioned above, Coursera does have a track record of re-using material and re-enabling access and it is possible that much of what is taken down will re-appear in the new system of specializations.

Comment: "Coursera does have a track record of re-using material and re-enabling access" -> https://www.class-central.com/report/coursera-old-platform-shutdown-download-courses/ seems to disagree: "Less than half of the 450+ courses currently hosted on the old platform are open to enrollment."